# how do I make button, input fill entire table cell? slight gaps are left

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fill an entire table cell with a button and another cell with a drop-down list.

If you have a look at my JSFiddle, I am having troubles with a slight gap between the cells and the table border.

I have tried several different approaches but I can't seem to figure out how to remove the gap.

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
input, select {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n8vbdskk/)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the big spaces above and below the input and select box then you can solve this by adding `height:auto` to `tr` tag instead of `height: 100px`.

If you mean that you want the input and select to touch the border then you can add `padding: 0px` to `td` tag.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nngL2j0s/1/)

Comment: This doesn't work... **Two problems**: **1.** This doesn't prevent the gap, at least in Chrome and Firefox on Windows **2.** `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` are obsolete. They are replaced in CSS with `table { border-spacing: 0 }` and `td { padding: 0 }` (and `border-collapse: collapse` is set, so this prevents the need for `border-spacing` in this case)

Comment: Thank you for your advice on the 2nd solution. I will update the post.
But for the first solution of mine, I don't mean to remove the slight gap from the gear, which I try to do is help him to remove the spaces upper and lower of the 2 input

Answer (score 1):

Your padding:0 need to be on td, not tr, so

```
td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

and with the button, the browser builds in a space for styling, so if you want it to be full you can do:

```
input[type=button]{ 
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

you will lose the 3d effect on the button though

Comment: This still has a 1px gap top and bottom in Chrome. `border: none` on the button and select is the only thing that removes it completely.